# Nested bxSlider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I would like to have a vertical carousel slider and inside each vertical slide I will have a horizontal slider, I am using bxSlider and it works well for vertical slider part but when I nest the horizontal part the horizontal slider doesn't work as expected.

Any idea on that?

Comment: Is there anything you've tried?

Comment: I tried every option but no luck, the first slider work but all the remaining don't. any other slider that support nesting can also be used

Answer (score 1):

Making a slider from multiple sliders is difficult even with a well documented one like bxSlider. Fortunately, I already made something that's pretty close to what your'e looking for. I couldn't get the horizontal child sliders to move as well, I think it might have to do with the fact that the parent slider moves vertically. I used the bxSlider option `preventDefaultSwipeY`on the parent Slider, but it wasn't very intuitive, the user would need to use the buttons to navigate. 
So instead I isolated the horizontal sliders by using iframes. Each horizontal nested slider is on it's own page which sits in the same directory of the main parent page. 
Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/mwqfgaom/1/), which has:

- Vertical carousel on the parent page.
- 6 horizontal sliders each on it's own separate page.
- The 6 iframes are nested in the vertical carousel.
- There are manual and automatic controls for the 6 horizontal sliders.
- There's a set of blue arrows to control the vertical slider.

Since you don't have an example posted, this is as close as I can get by guessing. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying back, your solution is what I am looking for but I don't have known number of rows in vertical sliders, the vertical rows basically shows the number of users and the horizontal sliders shows the task done by each user during the week, so in your case, if I have 100 users then I will have to create 100 files and iframes which isn't a viable option. Please correct me if I am wrong!!

Comment: You posted: _ ...when I nest the horizontal part the horizontal slider doesn't work as expected.
Any idea on that?_

Comment: Yes - But I am nesting the horizontal part in vertical carousel rows

Comment: _your solution is what I am looking for_  Ok. just to be clear I have shown you a vertical slider and inside that vertical slider are horizontal sliders, correct? [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/mwqfgaom/1/)  [link] (http://imgur.com/0m6JqET)  Vertical means up and down and is accoiated with columns, horizontal is right and left and is accociated with rows.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and add a demo to explain your issue specifically. The criteria of infinite vertical column sliders was not what you requested originally. You mentioned 100+ users after posting your question. Now it's infinite sliders. Imo that constitutes a whole new question. I wish you luck, sir, you'll need it.

Answer (score 0):

For a site I'm working on right now we're having a thumbnail based slider inside a thumbnail based slider. It did not work as expected. As in, the inner slider did not switch slides when clicking the thumbnails.

The thing I've found to fix this, is to reload the relevant inner slider when switching the outer slider by calling reloadSlider() on the inner slider. Make sure to cache your inner sliders in an array to easily reload the relevant slider. It's easy to use the onSlideAfter option in the outer slider to set up a function that reloads the relevant inner slider after the outer slider has finished it's transition.

Unfortunately, simply using the onSlideBefore option doesn't work for this. I'm guessing because the reload will then take place too soon. This can be worked around with a very short setTimeOut. Set up an onSlideBefore function inside the outer slider, that caches the target slide and sets up a slightly delayed reload for the inner slider.

Hope this helps!